# Error running ipython notebook on 64 bit

Tags: ipython, 32bit-64bit, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-14.04

When I am running ipython-notebook. Already install ipython and ipython notebook.

```
Ubuntu version : 14.04 with 64 Bit
```

When I run ipython, its running while running ipython-notebook, it shows error:

```
OSError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/libsodium.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I know the error. Error is that I am running 32 bit ipython into 64 bit. Can anyone help me to sort out this problem. Or any idea to substituting ipython 32 bit to 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mixture of 32 & 64 bit applications & libraries installed, easiest is to simply un-install iPython 64 bit and install the 32 bit.

Since you already have python installed you should (re)install ipython with:

```
sudo pip uninstall pyzmq ipython
```

*you will need to enter your password*

```
sudo pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

Do **not** skip re-building zmq

If you really need 64 bit either un-install all of python and install 64 bit from scratch - *hopefully all the libraries you need will be available as 64 bit* - or look into using python virtual-env to keep your installations discrete.

Comment: Thanks!. Few Days Earlier, I have uninstall a package by which all of their dependencies also got uninstall and my machine was crashed. So, If I uninstalled ipython will be the same. Any idea by which dependencies don't remove.

Comment: @ steve : I have uninstall ipython package but when I am reinstalling ipython again. It shows the same error that I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: _Which_ ipython are you installing

Comment: ipython 2.1.0 version

Comment: \Which build 32 bit or 64?

Comment: 32 bit because there is a file named as 'setupegg.py'. So I think its 32 bit package of ipython.